# Searching for the first occurrence of a char array substring inside a char array substring recursively in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, search, char

I'm trying to recursively search a character array for the first occurrence of a sequence comprised of another character array. I'm not allowed to use strings, predefined string functions, or loops. The character arrays that I'm searching in are names used in the program, and this function is used in another function that asks the user for an inputted substring, and then it searches the 5 names in the program for any that have an exact match of the substring input. I cannot post the rest of the code here. At the moment, my program is just always telling me that there are no names found regardless of the input that I put.

```
bool IsSubString(char name[], char search_str[], int i, int found_flag, int idx)
{
if (name[i] != '\0' && search_str[idx] != '\0')
    {
        if (search_str[idx] == name[i])
        {
            if (idx == 0)
            {
                found_flag = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                found_flag = found_flag * 1;
            }
            idx++;
        }
        else
        {
            found_flag = 0;
            idx = 0;
        }
        i++;
        IsSubString(name, search_str, i, found_flag, idx);
    }
    

    if (search_str[idx] == '\0')
        return found_flag;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to understand exactly what you are asking but from what I understood here are two solutions,

If you want to check if name[] == search_str[] :

```
bool IsEqual(char name[], char search_str[], int i)
{
    if (name[i] == '\0' && search_str[i] == '\0')
        return true;
    if (search_str[i] != name[i])
        return false;

    return IsEqual(name, search_str, ++i) 
}
```

If you want to get the index of the first occurrence of a substring in a given string :

```
/*
    str[] - The string to search in.
    search[] - The substring to search for.
    
    Returns -1 if substring not found.
*/
int getIndex(char str[], char search[], int index, int i,int j)
{
    if( search[j] == '\0' )
        return index;       // Substring found.
    if( str[i] == '\0' )
        return -1; // Search string ended but substring not found.

    if( str[i] == search[j] )
    {
        if( j == 0 ) index = i; // Sets index equal to the index of first charector of search in str 
        j++; ​
    ​}
    else 
    {
        index = -1; // Sets index back to -1 due to missmatched charector.
        j = 0;
    }
    
    return getIndex(str[], search[], index, ++i, j) // Continue search.
}
```

To use the function ,

```
getIndex(char_array_to_search, search_string, -1, 0 , 0);
```

for example ,

```
printf("%d",getIndex("the main string", "main", -1,0,0)); // prints 4
printf("%d",getIndex("one and one", "one", -1,0,0)); // prints 0
printf("%d",getIndex("one and one", "one", -1,1,0)); // prints 8
printf("%d",getIndex("nospace", "nos", -1,0,0)); // prints 0
```

You must pass -1 for index and 0 for j. If you pass any number greater than 0 for i the search will start from that index.

if you just want to know if the substring is present or not do,

```
bool found = getIndex(str, search, -1, 0,0) != -1;
```

Just for fun here is a much more compressed version, maybe to impress your teacher :

```
int getIndex(char str[], char search[], int index, int i,int j)
{
    if( search[j] == '\0' )
        return index;       // Substring found.
    if( str[i] == '\0' )
        return -1; // Search string ended but substring not found.

    index =  (j==0) * ((str[i] == search[j]) * (i + 1) - 1)  + (j!=0) * index;
    j += (str[i] == search[j]) - (str[i] != search[j])*j;
    
    return getIndex(str[], search[], index, ++i, j) // Continue search.
}
```

Comment: The last function is not meant for anything serious because it would be next to impossible for someone else to read. You could argue that it will avoid branch prediction but still, I won't consider it a good trade-off for readability.